# Excel indirect function to name a sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to have the worksheet of an external workbook update to a reference cell on a current work book.

This is my code so far.

```
=INDEX([Test.xlsx]indirect("I8")!$A$3:$B$7, MATCH(I8,[Test.xlsx]indirect("i8")!$A$3:$A$7,0),2)
```

Where Test is the external book and I8 is on the current book and sheet.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Indirect needs to have the whole part in it:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("[Test.xlsx]'" & I8 & "'!$A$3:$B$7"), MATCH(I8,INDIRECT("[Test.xlsx]'" & I8 & "'!$A$3:$A$7"),0),2)
```

Comment: So now I'm getting a reference error.  Do I need to designate the I8 is on the current workbook/sheet?

Comment: @user587822 I8 refers to the active sheet cell I8.  In that cell should be the name of the sheet to which you want to look in Workbook "Test.xlsx"  So either the sheet is named differently in I8 than in the workbook or "Test.xlsx" is named wrong and/or closed.

Comment: @user587822 did it work then?  If so please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do and it will mark this question as being answered.

Comment: is there anyway to path to the workbook, instead of just naming it?

Comment: That is a new question, but see [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-78344b0c-3458-474d-833e-6d0d55caf96a).  If you cannot make it work then come back and ask a new question.  The original question on how to use INDIRECT has been answered.